# Why can't I pass $ jQuery object as an argument in window.onload event's handler?

Tags: jquery

Since the global `$` shortcut for jQuery isn't available in WordPress, one must pass `$` into the function call. Passing `$` to `window.onload`'s event handler however yields the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Legal:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      //jQuery code
})
```

Illegal:

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function($){
      //jQuery code
})
```

Is this a result of window.onload event being a pure javascript event in the DOM and document.ready being a jQuery method?

Comment: jQuery runs with [no-conflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). `$` is just a valid variable or function name. Wordpress plugins may use `$` themselves so it is recommended to keep jQuery in no-conflict mode. Search the internet for the `jQuery $ is not a function name` error, you fill find blogs etc. explaining the same.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I was confused as both `window.onload` and `document.ready` are events why would the callback function's arguments for one not be supported by another. But it seems passing of `$` within the callback is unique to `.ready()` 's ability to reattach the alias.

Comment: Oh okay I misunderstood there. I'll describe it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the documentation for `.ready()` with `.load()` and you will find an interesting paragraph for `.ready`:

**Aliasing the jQuery Object**

When $.noConflict() is used to avoid namespace conflicts, the $ shortcut is no longer available. However, the .ready() handler is passed a reference to the jQuery object that called the method. This allows the handler to use a jQuery object, for example as $, without knowing its aliased name:

```js
jq2 = jQuery.noConflict();
jq2(function( $ ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here; the actual jQuery object is jq2
});
```

This means .ready has this convenience built in to pass jQuery as the first argument while .load has not.

You can simply `console.log($);` the parameter to find out what it is. The documentation also tells you.

What you did was naming the first parameter `$`, which is valid JavaScript. But this does not pass jQuery into the function. It will just name the first parameter `$`. The error message rightfully points out that it is not a function.
What the parameters for a function are can be read in their documentation.

**Links:**

- [.ready documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [.load documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)